# ggplot plots error bars but not actual data points in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, errorbar

I have a dataframe read in from a .csv which looks like this:

valley_cw_summary:

```
"","times","means","sd"
"1",1,23.7326530612245,0.822951942679513
"2",10,NA,NA
"3",11,27.9811602527283,2.18451736644603
"4",12,NA,NA
"5",13,28.8594485927628,2.47839597165728
"6",14,NA,NA
"7",15,28.5562894887995,2.4613545973872
"8",16,NA,NA
"9",17,26.9750287026406,1.87035639782657
"10",18,NA,NA
"11",19,25.2288340034463,1.0835585618286
"12",2,NA,NA
"13",20,NA,NA
"14",21,24.5269385410684,0.804365453635496
"15",22,NA,NA
"16",23,24.1512923607122,0.806920352501217
"17",24,NA,NA
"18",25,24.0809803921569,0.826911680243558
"19",3,23.5923254472014,0.889646609799541
"20",4,NA,NA
"21",5,23.3741488747836,0.932515616519176
"22",6,NA,NA
"23",7,23.2863296955773,0.982225553711973
"24",8,NA,NA
"25",9,25.4694252873563,1.33025859840695
```

I attempt to plot this with the following script:

```
ggplot(data=valley_c_w_summary,aes(x = times,y=means))+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(data = valley_c_w_summary,aes(x=times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(data=valley_c_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy May to December")
```

This plots only error bars (centered around the appropriate points as far as I can tell). I am plotting it with other such dataframes on the same plot, and they work fine, but they don't have any "NA"s, which leads me to believe they are the culprit. The full script of which looks like:

```
ggplot(data=ridge_cw_summary,aes(x = times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(data=ridge_c_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=means),colour="red")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(data = valley_c_w_summary,aes(x=times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(data=valley_c_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
  geom_line(data = edge_c_w_summary,aes(x=times,y=means),colour="blue")+
  geom_errorbar(data=edge_c_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="blue")+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy May to December")
```

How can I get ggplot to display the proper points?

Comment: What is `valley_c_w_summary`?

Comment: @J.Con It was a copy/paste error. I (hopefully) fixed it.

Comment: @J.Con To address your question directly, valley_c_w_summary is a dataframe read in from a .csv

Comment: Just wrap the call to the data in `na.omit`. Also, only make one call to the data in `ggplot`, and let the geoms inherit. Pared a bit, `ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x = times, y = means)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sd, ymax = means + sd))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alistaire comment sums up your answer, you need to put `na.omit` around your data frame also you don't need to call your data on each of the geoms, like below, I have copied your data and put it into a data frame called **vally_c_w_summary**:

```
ggplot(data=na.omit(valley_c_w_summary),aes(x = times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=means),colour="blue",size=1)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy May to December")
```

I got the below graph, I hope this is what you are expecting:

[image]

In case however, you need to approximate the NAs , you can use a function called **na.approx** in `zoo` library.

Your code would be something like below:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data.frame(na.approx(valley_c_w_summary)),aes(x = times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=means),colour="blue",size=1)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy May to December")
```

The output would be little different now, the error bars have increased. You can read about the documenation of spline and linear transformations of the `NA` approximation using `na.approx` [**here**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.7-14/topics/na.approx)

[image]